# Fastest repeated index add (np.add.at for multiple dimensions)

Tags: python, arrays, mapping, vectorization

Suppose I have an array `a` of shape `(N,)` with  `N~O(1e9)`.
Then I have a result array `b` of shape `(M1,M2,M2)`.

I then have an index array `f` of shape `(N,3)` where each row is an index to `b`.

What I want to accomplish as quickly as possible is the following result,

```
for i in range(N):
    b[*f[i]] += a[i]
```

Fancy indexing like `b[f[:,0],f[:,1],f[:,2]] += a` doesn't work because there are repeated indices in `f` so it will only add the last occurrence of each index to `b`.

If `b` was 1D then I could just do `np.add.at(b,f,a)`.

I'm looking for the fastest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), pass in a tuple of indices, like so -

```
np.add.at(b, (f[:,0], f[:,1], f[:,2]), a)
```

A faster way would be with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) after computing the linear indices, like so -

```
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(f.T,b.shape)
b += np.bincount(lidx, a, minlength=b.size).reshape(b.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, I find the np.bincount method is roughly 30 times faster with my large numbers!